# Multiple receivers on a 4-20mA loop with one of them with common ground

Tags: adc, 4-20ma

I'm trying to design a PCB to read some 4-20mA sensors in an already existing setup. The existing setup uses a NI 9207 adquisition board, which has an input impedance of 85 ohm per current channel, and the internal diagram is the following:
[image: NI 9207 internal diagram]

The diagram shows that all the current inputs have a common ground.

In this case, as I want to measure every sensor on the existing current loops, my guess is that I should hang a resistance before arriving this NI board. Then, my custom PCB should have the resistance "floating" and connect an ADC to both pins of that resistance in order to measure the voltage drop across it.

Should I have anything else in mind? I am wondering about the voltage levels, as my PCB will probably be powered via USB (with a wall adapter from 230V AC) and the sensors and everything else will be powered directly with 230V AC. I am wondering if I could have any trouble reading the voltage across the resistance. Let's say we have a signal of 20mA, my resistance is 120ohm and ideal cables. The voltage-drop accross this resistance would be 20mA * 120ohm=2.4V. The voltage-drop at the NI board will be 20mA * 85ohm=1.7V, which is my resistance low-side voltage. The high-side voltage will be 1.7V + 2.4V=4.1V. **Here is my question**: are both grounds related? Because, if so, I would need my ADC to be powered at 5V level in order not to saturate. I was thinking on powering all the PCB at the 3V voltage level, that is why I would clarify this issue before I start with the HW design.

Many thanks in advance,

Manuel

------------------Edit
I lay here a quick schematic of what I am thinking
[image: Quick schematic]

Comment: May be a rcv420 chip might suit? Its designed specifically for your application.

Comment: Hi Kartman, many thanks for answering. No, that chip won't do, because a) it is supplied at 12-36V, and b) we're trying to make a small device, and this chip seems to be quite large. I'm just more curious about the question posted initially, about the ground effect on the supply needs of the ADC chip

Comment: Draw a schematic of what you’re proposing.

Comment: Are both grounds related? Yes. If your circuit is floating in relation to the other circuit, then your circuit only sees the voltage across your sense resistor. Otherwise you can use two adc channels and compute the difference or use a differential amplifier to do it in the analog domain. A Microchip PAC193x or TI high side current chip will doit for you.

Comment: @Kartman I have just added a quick schematic. As drawn, yes, both GNDs are related. In the real scenario I am thinking that the "only" link between both circuits is the 230V neutral cable, that might tie both circuits grounds... About the floating circuit, being other PCB and device different from the one generating the signal, is the resistor floating? I am thinking that maybe the best thing to do is just lay a 4.5V LDO from the USB line and power the ADCs with it, so I have some room for the signal

Comment: Conceptually the tl081 would work, in reality it won’t. You would need to chose your parts carefully. TI ina199 or ina219 are possible candidates.

Comment: If I understand your intention correctly, you want to run your custom hardware simultaneously with the existing system from NI. To achieve galvanic isolation, you could use magnetic current sensors in series to your NI card inputs with voltage outputs or even direct digital outputs. For example, I have had a good experience with sensors from Allegro MicroSystems.

Comment: I'm thinking of just using a power meter (such as the INA228 or the PAC1934, because I want to measure 10 4-20mA loops) and use it for measuring the currents, do you think it can work?